# How to rewrite url domain.com/?id=123456 => domain.com/123456/

Tags: php, url, seo, search-engine, friendly-url

How do I make a site with Search Engine friendly urls? Do I need special PHP code instead of:

```
$_GET['id']
```

How to access 'id' variable after rewriting URL?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please. FYI, there are **lots** of tutorials out there explaining how to do this *exactly*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to your htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /(.*) ?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

note: if you already have

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
```

on your htaccess file, just place

```
RewriteRule /(.*) ?id=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

under it and ignore the rest

instead of visiting domain.com/?id=123456, you now visit domain.com/123456/. then on that page you can still use $_GET['id'] the way you normally would

Comment: thank you, what if there are two variables in url domain.com/?id1=123&id2=456

Answer (score 0):

In your example you just need below code in your .htaccess file, in main directory.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule /(.*) ?id=$1
```

Don't forget to create your links `domain.com/123456` style. Web server will resolve `domain.com/123456`correctly. For example:

```
<a href='domain.com/123456'>the link</a>
```

This is very basic question and there are millions of tutorials on internet. Just make some googling buddy.

Comment: How to access 'id' variable after rewriting URL?

Comment: You are defining it here `RewriteRule /(.*) ?id=$1` If you would type `RewriteRule /(.*).html ?id=$1` It would need the url as `domain.com/123456.html`